# Async callback function in jquery .done() not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, async-await

Why does giving an async function as a callback function for a jQuery [`deferred.done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) not work? i.e. Why does

```
jqueryObj.fadeTo("slow", 1)
    .promise().done(asyncFunc);
```

not work, but

```
jqueryObj.fadeTo("slow", 1)
    .promise().done(function() {
        asyncFunc();
    );
```

does?

(Also, note that `jqueryObj.click(asyncFunc)` *does* work.)

---

Example:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

After the title has finished faded in, each item of the list fades in, in order. The fade time is 20000 ms, but the delay between list items is 250 ms (so the next list item starts fading in while the previous is still ongoing).

JS:

```
var title = $("h2"),
    listItems = $("ul li");

function wait(delay) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, delay);
  });
}

async function reveal() {
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        $(listItems[i]).fadeTo(2000, 1);
        await wait(250);
    }
}

title.fadeTo(500, 1)
    //.promise().done(reveal) doesn't work!
    .promise().done(function() {
        reveal();
    });
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsxkqzp1/2/) showing the desired effect. You can try swapping for the commented out line to see nothing happens. The commented out line is how you normally expect functions to work

Comment: In a comment on my deleted answer, you said you don't want to wait for the fadeTo to complete, you just want a 250ms delay between them. Your fiddle above does that (on a browser that supports `async`/`await`).

Comment: I've edited the question to try and improve the clarity. The Question is at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that prior to jQuery 3 , [$.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (jQuery promise api) was not [Promises A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) compliant.

In order to pass a reference to an `async` function  use `then()`(more standard promise method) instead of `done()` and use jQuery v3+

```
title.fadeTo(1000, 1).promise().then(reveal)
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9x6bv9b/)

Comment: Ah, right! I've noticed choosing "jQuery (edge)" in JSFiddle means `.done(reveal)` does work; maybe they're bring `.done()` up to standards.

Comment: Works only on `JQ edge`? because JSFiddle provided by OP is having 2.1.3

Comment: @Bharadwaj I realize what OP is using. Am answering why OP code not working as asked and providing requirements to make it work as shown

Answer (score 2):

This is because jQuery prior to version 3 simply doesn't support async delegates

Your first code is equivalent of:

```
jqueryObj.fadeTo("slow", 1)
    .promise().done(async() => await asyncFunc());
```

and not the code you provided.

This code doesn't work as well and this is because when you check the jQuery sources - it checks for
`($.type === 'function')` when you are registering a delegate.

For async function the .type returned is 'object' and not a 'function' and therefore it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally sure that this is the reason, however, this is weird enough to be strongly suspect:

try this code:

```
$.isFunction(reveal); //returns false instead of true
```